# "No batteries available" Kubuntu 18.04 - Acer Aspire E 15 (E5-573T)

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, indicator, battery, acer

I just made a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04 (64 bits) on my Acer Aspire E 15 (E5-573T-POVK), but the battery isn't detected. The indicator shows "No batteries available", and `upower --dump` gives

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         no
  updated:              mer. 18 juil. 2018 15:21:38 CEST (43 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       none
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.7
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  no
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

I tried this driver: [Battery kernel module for Acer Switch](https://github.com/jfrimmel/Acer-Switch-Battery-Module), upower now detects a battery, but bus addresses aren't correct so battery level is shown as 0